# Missing guidance in audits: Keeping in mind what guidance above?

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, user-interface, review-audits

I just 'failed'  a First Questions audit. The [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEgqF.png) reads:

> **STOP! Look and Listen.**
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.**
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

I noted that most review queues have some explanation ('guidance') of why your choice was wrong and what the right choice would be (e.g. There were no major problems with this question, you should correct minor problems with Edit or click Leave Open).

However in this case (<kbd>Share feedback</kbd> on a known good post) there was no 'guidance' beyond the **You didn't pass** which is not really 'guidance' in and of itself. But then later, the last sentence references the nonexistent 'guidance above.' There may be more queues and/or review audit cases that result in a lack of 'guidance' provided to reviewers, but then the 'guidance' is referenced later on in the failure message, but sharing feedback on a known good question is one of them.

Please ensure that all review audit failure scenarios have a sentence or so of 'guidance' so that the last clause, which is apparently common to all failure messages, does not make a bizarre reference to 'guidance' that is not shown.

Comment: I'm guessing this comes from the old review UI and the text wasn't updated with the 2019 UI revamp.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Another guess is that, since the First Questions queue is new, as there used to be First Posts instead, they might have simply forgotten to add the guidance to the audits.